# Can I use GoogleMap or other GPS data in creation of the Graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

I have following graph.

```
    g = Graph[{"Uppsala" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "Uppsala", 
    "UpplandsVasby" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
    "UpplandsVasby" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
    "Stockholm" -> "Boo", "Boo" -> "Stockholm", 
    "Stockholm" -> "Lidingo", "Lidingo" -> "Stockholm", 
    "Stockholm" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "Stockholm", 
    "Stockholm" -> "Taby", "Taby" -> "Stockholm"}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 40];

coords = CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ VertexList[g];

SetProperty[g, {VertexCoordinates -> Reverse[coords, 2], 
  Prolog -> {Gray, CountryData["Sweden", "Polygon"]}}]
```

Based on the real road connection on the GoogleMap or other GPS data ,how can I set my `Edge`cover the actual road connection between cities and the actual distance(in Km) based on the GoogleMap stays as a `EdgeCost`. For example,I want to set these two cities as two vertexes of the my edge in the graph `"Uppsala" -> "Marsta"`(which is already). But as you can see the edge between two cities is just an arrow connecting two geographical locations of cities.I wanted them to use GoogleMap(or other GPS data) and set my edge on the map based on the shortest suggested route of GoogleMap.And set the calculated distance as EdgeCost value of created edge.Is it possible?

Comment: For example,I want to set these two cities as two vertexes of the my edge in the graph `"Uppsala" -> "Marsta"`(which is already). But as you can see the edge between two cities is just an arrow connecting two geographical locations of cities.I wanted them to use GoogleMap(or other GPS data) and set based on the shortest suggested route of GoogleMap as my edge on the map.And set the calculated distance as `EdgeCost` value of created edge.

Comment: Hi,many thanks but this is not just about importing data from GoogleMap.It is about how to set the required data in the `Graph`. Please read the question again.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's a piece of the puzzle:

```
c1 = CityData["Boston", "Coordinates"];
c2 = CityData["New York", "Coordinates"];
address = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" <>
    ToString[c1[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[c1[[2]]] <> "&destinations=" <>
    ToString[c2[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[c2[[2]]] <> "&sensor=false"
```

which I modified from the [google directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/). Now you can get the data from google:

```
distData = Import[address]
```

Per rm-rf's suggestion, you can get cleaner (easier to parse input) using

```
distData = Import[address, "JSON"]
```

which gives

```
{"destination_addresses" -> {"801 Montgomery Street, Brooklyn, NY 11213, USA"}, 
 "origin_addresses" -> {"Head Island Causeway, Boston, MA 02127, USA"}, 
 "rows" ->  {{"elements" -> {{"distance" -> {"text" -> "349 km", "value" -> 349019}, 
              "duration" -> {"text" -> "3 hours 45 mins", "value" -> 13477}, 
              "status" -> "OK"}}}}, 
 "status" -> "OK"}
```

Indexing into this

```
First[First[distData[[3, 2]]]][[2, 1, 1, 2, 1]]
```

gives

```
"text" -> "349 km"
```

Comment: I think you could do `Import[..., "JSON"]` for cleaner data

Comment: I think we have to be aware of this detail: "Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of information on a Google Map; for example, to determine origin-destination pairs that fall within a specific driving time from one another, before requesting and displaying those destinations on a map. **Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a Google map is prohibited.**". This information can be accessed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

Comment: Some syntax sugestion `address=ToString@StringForm["http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\`1\`,\`2\`&destinations=\`3\`,\`4\`&sensor=false",c1[[1]],c1[[2]],c2[[1]],c2[[2]]]` and a more general way to parse JSON `Cases[distData, 
 HoldPattern["distance" -> {_ -> km_, _} ] :> km , \[Infinity]]`

Comment: As of MMA 11 you can have a look at 'TavelDistance'

Answer (score 3):

This is only an attempt to answer the question, **if** I understood it correctly. You want to *"cover the actual road connection between cities (...) based on the GoogleMap"*.

**First step**: find the coordinates of the two cities you want to use as *edges* in your graphic:

```
c1 = CityData["Sao Paulo", "Coordinates"];
c2 = CityData["Rio de Janeiro", "Coordinates"];
```

**Second step**: define the center of the map:

```
center = (c1 + c2)/2;
```

**Third step**: `Import[]` the actual Google Maps image based on the center you've specified

```
Import["http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" <>ToString[center[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[center[[2]]] <> "&zoom=6&size=400x400&sensor=false&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:O%7C" <> ToString[c1[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[c1[[2]]] <>"&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C" <> ToString[c2[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[c2[[2]]]]
```

[image]

**EDITED**

After some research, I think it can also be done:

Define the cities:

```
from = ToString[c1[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[c1[[2]]];
to = ToString[c2[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[c2[[2]]];
```

Now use *Mathematica* to import data from Google with distance and time:

```
distdata = Import["http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" <> from <> "&destination=" <> to <> "&region=es&sensor=false", {"HTML", "Source"}];
```

Now find distance by road:

```
roadDistance = StringSplit[StringSplit[distdata, ":"][[13]],","][[1]]
```

> "429 km"

Now find travel time:

```
travelTime = StringSplit[StringSplit[distdata, ":"][[16]], ","][[1]]
```

> "4 hours 44 mins"

Comment: I presume what the OP means with the quoted sentence is that they want to set the cost of the edge between the two cities (which are the vertices) to be equal to the distance (on road, which is why they're using Google maps) between them. This edge cost will, perhaps, be used in optimization/TSP/other algorithms to calculate the cost in moving something from A to B/finding the cheapest route (not necessarily the fastest/shortest), etc.

Comment: @rm-rf YES you are right.The whole problem is to optimize the graph cost based on the GoogleMap real distances.Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Alex So you actually don't need to create a **graphic**? You need to compute **distances** based on Google Maps/GPS? So I think it would be interesting to edit the question and put something more clear like "Can I use Google Maps or GPS data to compute road distances"?

Comment: @RodLm many thanks!! please read it carefully it is not "graphic".It is `Graph`.Yes!!! in the beginning, it has to compute the road distances and this is part of the solution but not all.In the end, I want to show my Graph (inducing vertexes and edges(real roads))on GoogleMap picture.Any idea?

Comment: @Alex If you want to compute distances using Google Maps I think one approach is to **decode** the *Google Directions API polylines* and compute distances directly from it... I know it can be done in C# and Java... However I'm stil wondering how to do this with *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Alex I don't know about interfacing with the Google maps API, but Mark has [worked on it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3435/5) quite a bit... you might find some info in that post (and follow on to his website from his profile, where he has a little more on that). I don't know if they're actually relevant to your problem though...

Comment: @rm-rf many thanks but there is just how to create an interactive map in Mathematica.You got it very right in your first comment that I need to create a graph and optimize the network cost.I need visualization just to show the Graph.The main task is how to specify the cities(vertexes) and roads(edges) based on GPS data.

Comment: Here's the API you want to use: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/ to get the distance data