# How can I use Mathematica to get the translated result from the Google Translate webpage?

Tags: import

I would like to use Mathematica to automatically translate some input texts, from one language to the other one, then apply some manipulation of a string on the text. I know how to realize the manipulation of the string, however, I do not know how can I cite the result from Google translation neither how to use Mathematica to give the input text to the webpage.

I believe there should be a solution, however, I have no knowledge about webpage or any relating programming language. So if anyone can give me some suggestions about what material I should read, or, the example notebook of citing the result of webpage will be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: What do you mean by citing?  The format for citing depends, to some extent, on the journal in which you're publishing.  Consult an appropriate manual.  Or do you mean something else?  [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html), perhaps?

Comment: You need to use the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs). [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30748/export-to-google-spreadsheet-with-oauthauthentication) might let you authenticate with the API, but it's not for sure since that method doesn't work with all of Google's APIs. I believe this is a duplicate of that question since specific details of an API that is not Mathematica related is out of scope.

Comment: You can try `URLFetch[http://www.google.com/translate_c?langpair=en|it&u=http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85559/how-can-i-use-mathematica-to-get-the-translated-result-from-the-webpage-google]`  note theres some interactive prompts so Im guessing it won't work.