# Google Drive API connection: (or how can I build a service connection to an OAuth2 service?)

Tags: customization, webservices, paclets, authentication

From [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147196/38205) I know how to build a a basic service connection.

And that's fine in simple authentication cases but how do I do this for OAuth services?

Even more specifically, how can I do this for Google Drive?

Answer (score 20):

#### Code

[See this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147547/38205) for the main issue that made it take so long to get this up

If you just want the service connection you can get it like this:

```
PacletInstall["ServiceConnection_GoogleDrive",
 "Site"->"http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
 ]
```

#### Post

So this turned out to be a bit of a bear to get the details right for, but not terribly complex once they're dealt with.

Mathematica's built-in OAuth package has some inline docs which are helpful, but there was a lot of trial an error too.

Mostly, we need to provide the following parameters in the `"ClientInfo"` field (i.e. the one that lays-out how to implement the authentication):

```
"AuthorizeEndpoint"
```

Which is the endpoint from which we pass our auth code.

For google this is: `"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"`

```
"AccessEndpoint"
```

The endpoint from which we get the auth token after obtaining an auth code.

For google this is: `"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"`

```
"RedirectURI"
```

The standard OAuth redirect URI. I set this up like so (well I put in a helper function in my template package that implements this at run time):

```
HTTPHandling`StartWebServer[
 URLDispatcher[{___~~"oauth2callback"~~___}:>
  APIFunction[{code},<display_code>]
 ]
```

Note that this is maybe even easier to do by creating a [`ChannelObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChannelObject.html) to redirect to -- alternatively we could do something more than just display our auth code with the [`APIFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html) too.

Then we need both

```
"ConsumerKey"
```

and

```
"ConsumerSecret"
```

I have an encoded keychain mechanism (implemented with [`Encode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encode.html)) built into my standard suite of tools so I just save these here.

You get these by registering an application at https://console.developers.google.com. I made one called MathematicaLink, but, alas, I can't share the client secret (literally -- Google doesn't allow this). Also see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071856/how-to-get-client-secret-from-google-developers-console-in-ios) for a quick rundown on how to get that.

The last thing one needs for OAuth2 is a scope. This seems not to be adequately handled by the standard dialog so I had to cook this in myself.

But first, we'll need the `"AuthenticationDialog"` parameter:

```
(
 OAuthClient`tokenOAuthDialog[
   gooledriveauthorizationendpointurl@#,
   "GoogleDrive",
   googledrivedata["icon"]
   ] &)
```

We mostly just use the standard built-in token dialog, but notice the `gooledriveauthorizationendpointurl`. The OAuth client seems to pass an incorrect `"scope"` (it's blank). So that function will need to re-parse the passed URL and correct the scope. It's simple, but I generalized and so my block of code is more than I want to put there.

Then since we've passed all the requisite junk the `` OAuthSigning` `` package will operate correctly (for those interested in just getting tokens via this method that's where you'll want to dig around. Check out `` OAuthSigning`Private`OAuthFlow `` to see how to get an access token from all of this data).

So here's a quick auth example rundown.

First the basic auth dialog:

[image: token dialog]

Before that opens, if I'm coming from a fresh restart, it asks me for my keychain password (because of how I set it up -- not implemented by the `` OAuth` `` package), but otherwise just opens that. Follow the link, choose the appropriate Google account and approve:

[image: approve]

When I do this it routes to the redirect URI started with `StartWebServer`:

[image: web server port]

I copy that key in:

[image: key]

And the OAuth package takes care of the rest.

[image: service object]

And then just checking that the access token is being handled correctly:

```
In[11]:= $gd["ListFiles"]["files", All, "id"] // Normal // First

Out[11]= "1CfpLOne3LRBHXPFRNtlzjujuq66qIzX47ezNdr_XPls"
```

I'll get this paclet up for public consumption after I provide access to more than just the files API and make sure uploads work (I remember from a previous implementation of a Google Drive connection that it was a bit hairy -- hopefully the ServiceConnect framework smooths that out).

Comment: I installed the packlet `PacletInstall["ServiceConnection_GoogleDrive",
 "Site"->"http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
 ]` to run MMA codes placed in  Google Drive. But after installation, I do not know what to do to run the codes in GoogleDrive. I receive the message:  `Paclet[ServiceConnection_GoogleDrive,1.0.2, <>] `. Can you guide me step by step what to do next? Thank you.