# what is equivalent of dataset when using with APIFunction?

Tags: dataset, cloud-deploy, apifunction

I am researching on building a backend for website using Wolfram.  APIFunction is great to use, but I can't figure out how should I store data like using dataset in a local notebook when using APIFunction.  There are 3 of that, databin, clouddeploy[dataset], dataexpression, didn't figure out which way should be THE way to go?  And can support multithread at the minimum and some volume when multiple users are calling the API the same time.

Here is simple code showing what I am trying to do.

```
data1 = Dataset[<|"a"->"testa","b"->"testb"|>];

CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"c"->String}, Block[{dataA,datab},
                    dataA,datab = somehowGotFrom[c];
                    AppendTo[data1,<|"a"->dataA,"b"->dataB|>];]
```

I got the APIFunction working all well, the data reached the cloud deployed API, but the data1 is not in the cloud and didn't collect the data through API.

My question is how should I store data collected through APIFunction.  Confused from the docs.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried and where are you stuck? Try to keep examples minimal. API can be called by multiple users at the same time but you need to make it public and keep track of your cloud credits.

Comment: @Kuba,  added some simplified code in trying to illustrate.

Comment: I am kinda confused by your question, but we should start by keeping things simple. Use a simple List instead instead of a Dataset and use a CloudExpression. The code you're looking for is ```CloudExpression["myList"] = {};``` and ```AppendTo[CloudExpression["myList"], something]```

Comment: Alternatively you could use a Databin. See the Databin documentation for examples of how to use them.

Comment: @Searke, databin has size limit, doesn't scale very well.  Also, that is just a simplified code, dataset is better than list for my case.

Comment: Does `CloudExpression` fit your needs? Is this essentially the same question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153114/5478?