# Error: Cannot import data as JSON format, Khan Academy API

Tags: import, warning-messages, web-access, json-format

### Problem context

I'm updating my [working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151847/oauth-for-khan-academy-api) Mathematica Khan Academy reporting application.  Since updating to 11.2 I'm having some errors importing via the [Khan Academy API](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API) as JSON.  Update: This particular issue is broken in 11.0.1 and 11.2

Specifically, when making the same query with different "ListId" values, each representing a class of students I'm "coaching" in Khan Academy, one class works and the other returns an error: `"Cannot import Data as JSON format"`

### What I've tried

```
link = "https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/students/\
progress?dt_start=2017-10-22T07:00:00.000Z&dt_end=2017-10-29T06:59:59.\
999Z&listId=\
ag5zfmtoYW4tYWNhZGVteXJsCxIIVXNlckRhdGEiRnVzZXJfaWRfa2V5X2h0dHA6Ly9pZC\
5raGFuYWNhZGVteS5vcmcvYThlN2M3MWFiYjliNGJhZjg3OWM5ZTIxODQwMWQ5NWIMCxIL\
U3R1ZGVudExpc3QYgICAgKCOgQoM&studentsPerRequest=50&extended=1&tz_\
offset=-420&lang=en";

URLRead[HTTPRequest[
  OAuthSigning`Private`HMACSha1SignatureService[link, "HMAC", 
   "GET", $consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenParams[
    "oauth_token"], $accessTokenParams["oauth_token_secret"]]]]
```

Returns:

[image]

```
Import[HTTPRequest[

  OAuthSigning`Private`HMACSha1SignatureService[link, "HMAC", 
   "GET", $consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenParams[
    "oauth_token"], $accessTokenParams["oauth_token_secret"]]
          ]]
```

Returns:

[image]

```
URLExecute[HTTPRequest[

  OAuthSigning`Private`HMACSha1SignatureService[link, "HMAC", 
   "GET", $consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenParams[
    "oauth_token"], $accessTokenParams["oauth_token_secret"]]
          ]]
```

Returns:

[image]

And when I click on the link, in the web it says, `"OAuth error. Nonce already used: 15Y3zVd9cGGR6jQjGcogv043"`

### But!

When I try this with another link, which only contains a different ListId (representing a different class of students I'm managing), everything works as expected.  I am able to use other API endpoints with this class, without error so I know that the ListId is valid.  Also, its strange but true, Khan Academy [encourages the use of](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Authentication#the-endpoints-exposed-on-the-api-explorer-dont-seem-to-do-what-i-need-am-i-ableallowed-to-access-any-other-endpoints) undocumented, private API endpoints.

Comment: JSON can sometimes break when importing characters not in UTF-8. Try using `Import[#, "JSON", "StrictDecoding" -> False]`.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1 I just tried it and it didn't work.  Any ideas why I'd get the `nonce already used` error?

Comment: That's the second time you're trying to read from the URL. Try generating the URL with the ``OAuthSigning`...`` call and simply going there. Also what do the guts of the `HTTPResponse` look like? (qualitatively, i.e. is there data cached in it that you can work look at to see what's gone wrong)

Comment: Okay @b3m2a1 I just tried this: https://gist.github.com/matthewalangreen/0d57e93472b60684fff631c9a41caed5 and I'm still getting the `cannot import data as JSON format` error

Comment: Try importing as `"Text"` to see what could be messing up the JSON import

Comment: Okay, I was able to import as text.  That's good news. I can't share the response with you because it contains student data.  Any suggestions of how to figure out what might be messing up the JSON?  Or how to convert it to JSON?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67827/discussion-between-matt-green-and-b3m2a1).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @b3m2a1 for all the [help](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67827/discussion-between-matt-green-and-b3m2a1), we were able to get this to work:

```
link = "https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/students/\
progress?dt_start=2017-10-22T07:00:00.000Z&dt_end=2017-10-29T06:59:59.\
999Z&listId=\
ag5zfmtoYW4tYWNhZGVteXJsCxIIVXNlckRhdGEiRnVzZXJfaWRfa2V5X2h0dHA6Ly9pZC\
5raGFuYWNhZGVteS5vcmcvYThlN2M3MWFiYjliNGJhZjg3OWM5ZTIxODQwMWQ5NWIMCxIL\
U3R1ZGVudExpc3QYgICAgKCOgQoM&studentsPerRequest=50&extended=1&tz_\
offset=-420&lang=en";


httpReq = 
  HTTPRequest[
   OAuthSigning`Private`HMACSha1SignatureService[link, "HMAC", 
    "GET", $consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenParams[
     "oauth_token"], $accessTokenParams["oauth_token_secret"]]];

data = ImportString[ExportString[Import[httpReq, "Text"], "Text"], 
   "JSON"];
```

I'm still working to understand the details, but it seems that simply importing the data as JSON throws an error that `ExportString` handles for us and allows the data to import. I'd love to understand this further if y'all have any ideas.

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154476/280) can be relevant.

Comment: Can you tell us what headers you get? Especially content-type and content-encoding.

Comment: This is what I get from `HTTPResponse[HTTPReq]` "application/json;charset=utf-8". @Kuba. Do you need more info?

Comment: @MattGreen I guess the issue it the same as in linked topic. Nothing more to add here. But you can check if this isn't a faster workaround: `ImportString[ToCharacterCode @ URLRead[..., "BodyBytes"], "JSON"]`