# Acessing data in google drive

Tags: files-and-directories, webservices

I have a directory in Google Drive I would like to directly access and process data and save the outputs in the same drive. It is a personal drive.  At first I thought would be so starigfhtforward as Dropbox.
I have also seen some questions on this [issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147451/google-drive-api-connection-or-how-can-i-build-a-service-connection-to-an-oaut#new-answer)  but I had the impression this would be to connect an app rather than just processing files which I think it should be somehow simpler.

So if there is a tutorial for an end-user rather than a developer I would appreciate or perhaps face the fact it needs some skills to get involved in this issue.

Comment: Google Drive supports something called [Google Backup and Sync](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987) which makes it work like Dropbox. My API connection targets the case where you _don't_ want everything to sync to your desktop

Comment: You can also use something like Google drive Filestream to mount the drive as a directory on your filesystem...and then just walk through the directory structure and read/create files as needed.