# Obfuscate the code for a function

Tags: function-construction

I have written a Mathematica package on game theory (containing functions that tests whether a game is perfect recall, finds optimal strategies for a player in a game, etc.) and would like people to be able to use it (execute its functions). However, I don't want people to be able to analyze how the algorithms work. Is there a way (does Mathematica have the feature or have someone made a program) to obfuscate Mathematica functions so that a function is translated to another function that works exactly the same in terms of input-output but is completely unreadable? I don't need to have the obfuscated function be translatable back to the original function (using a secret keyword, as in encryption-decryption scheme), because I have the original function saved privately anyway.

As a comparison, Maple 2018 has this (new) feature: https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/new_features/Maple2018/EncryptedProcedures.aspx

Comment: I think you need `Encode`?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=89&v=596&p=1

Comment: It isn't obvious how to do this, aside from creating a deployed CDF like in the video linked above.  You could make a WL package, written to an MX file so the source isn't readable.  You can set your functions to have the `ReadProtected` attribute, but there isn't a way to hide the `DownValues` from users.

Comment: @JasonB. actually if you also supply `Locked` along with `ReadProtected` no definitions can be read.

Answer (score 12):

This is what a combination of `Locked`, `Encode`, and `ReadProtected` do for you. As xczd notes in the comments, [`Encode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encode.html) makes the source code unreadable to humans. You can also supply an encoding key, as I do [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148521/38205).

Then if you set both [`Locked`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locked.html) and [`ReadProtected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadProtected.html) you won't be able to inspect the `DownValues` (or any `*Values`) of your symbol. Here's an example that allows you to make a cache where the cache keys and values can't be read:

```
SetAttributes[Caches`$myCache, {ReadProtected, Locked}]
Caches`$myCache["user"] = "password";
Caches`$myCache // DownValues

General::readp: Symbol Caches`$myCache is read-protected.

$Failed

Caches`$myCache["user"]

"password"
```

Note that `Locked` is a *heavy* attribute, though. I can no-longer change any of the [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) of this function, nor can I remove it.

```
Caches`$myCache // Remove

Remove::rmlck: Symbol Caches`$myCache is Locked and cannot be removed.
```

One other subtle thing worth noting is that `ReadProtected` alone is not enough:

```
SetAttributes[Caches`$myCache2, {ReadProtected}]
Caches`$myCache2["user"] = "password";
Caches`$myCache2 // DownValues

{HoldPattern[Caches`$myCache2["user"]] :> "password"}
```