# Adding subscripts to variables

Tags: variable-definitions

I know I can define

```
vars = Map[Subscript[x, #1] &, {"tem", "pressure", "hum", "lat", "alt", "space", "corner"}]
```

and

```
vars = Array[Subscript[x, #1] &, {8}]
```

But how can I add both kinds of subscripts in my "x"s to get something like  x"tem""1", x"tem""2", and so on?

Based on the answer I got here, I tried to write general form in this way.I am quite sure there would be much better interactive way to do that.This is just starter version of mine:

```
Outer[Subscript[x, Subscript[#1, #2], Subscript[#3, #4], 
Subscript[#5, #6], Subscript[#7, #8]] &, {"a", "b"}, {1, 2, 3, 
4}, {"i", "j"}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {"m", "n"}, {1, 2}, {"A", "B", "C", 
"D"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a somewhat different approach to defining a function to make subscripted variables in of the requested form. The algorithm doesn't differ substantially from the one used by Rod Lm; the difference lies in the way I use multiple function definitions, pattern matching, and destructuring of the formal argument sequences.

```
SetAttributes[fancySubscript, HoldFirst]
fancySubscript[var_Symbol, tag_String, index_Integer] /; 
    Not[ValueQ[var]] :=
  Subscript[var, tag <> ToString[index]]
fancySubscript[var_Symbol, tags : {_String ..}, index_Integer] /; 
    Not[ValueQ[var]] :=
  fancySubscript[var, #, index] & /@ tags
fancySubscript[var_Symbol, tags : {_String ..}, 
   indices : {_Integer ..}] /; Not[ValueQ[var]] :=
  fancySubscript[var, tags, #] & /@ indices
```

The condition `Not[ValueQ[var]` ensures that `fancySubscript` doesn't accept variables having values.

```
a = 42; fancySubscript[a, "tag", 2]
```

> fancySubscript[a, "tag", 2]

The overloaded definitions ensure that `fancySubscript` accepts all the following forms:

```
fancySubscript[b, "tag", 2]
```

> $b_{\text{tag2}}$

```
fancySubscript[b, {"foo", "bar", "baz"}, 2]
```

> $\left\{b_{\text{foo2}},b_{\text{bar2}},b_{\text{baz2}}\right\}$

```
fancySubscript[b, {"foo", "bar", "baz"}, Range@3]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  b_{\text{foo1}} & b_{\text{bar1}} & b_{\text{baz1}} \\
>  b_{\text{foo2}} & b_{\text{bar2}} & b_{\text{baz2}} \\
>  b_{\text{foo3}} & b_{\text{bar3}} & b_{\text{baz3}} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

#### Edit

To answer the question raised in a comment by Alex, it is easy to change `fancySubscript` to do double indexing, rather than concatenating the tags and indices. The only modification required is to redefine the first definition of `fancySubscript` as

```
fancySubscript[var_Symbol, tag_String, index_Integer] /; 
    Not[ValueQ[var]] := 
  Subscript[var, tag, index]
```

With this change, for example,

```
fancySubscript[b, {"foo", "bar", "baz"}, 2]
```

gives

> $\left\{b_{\text{foo},2},b_{\text{bar},2},b_{\text{baz},2}\right\}$

Comment: nice job!!!Thats the way to do it.

Comment: @Rod LM sorry Rod but it is much better version of your work.you still have my invitation to a drink "PLus" Mr. Goldberg!!

Comment: how can we write it in very general form of `Subscript[x, Subscript["a", "i"], Subscript["b", "j"], Subscript["c", "k"], Subscript["d", "f"], Subscript["...", "..."]]`

Comment: Are you changing your question to request that the tags and indices be separate subscripts?. I think that could be done by combining my answer with Mr.Wizard's. Because of 4th of July festivities, I don't have time to work it out today. If no one else does (unlikely), I look into it later.

Comment: yes I mean exactly that.Happy 4th July and wish you and your family really a good time there!!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this?

```
names = {"tem", "pressure", "hum", "lat", "alt", "space", "corner", "snow"};
vars = Table[Subscript[x, names[[y]] <> ToString[#]], {y, 1, 8}] & /@ Range@8
```

> $
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  x_{\text{tem1}} & x_{\text{pressure1}} & x_{\text{hum1}} & x_{\text{lat1}} & x_{\text{alt1}} & x_{\text{space1}} & x_{\text{corner1}} & x_{\text{snow1}} \\
>  x_{\text{tem2}} & x_{\text{pressure2}} & x_{\text{hum2}} & x_{\text{lat2}} & x_{\text{alt2}} & x_{\text{space2}} & x_{\text{corner2}} & x_{\text{snow2}} \\
>  x_{\text{tem3}} & x_{\text{pressure3}} & x_{\text{hum3}} & x_{\text{lat3}} & x_{\text{alt3}} & x_{\text{space3}} & x_{\text{corner3}} & x_{\text{snow3}} \\
>  x_{\text{tem4}} & x_{\text{pressure4}} & x_{\text{hum4}} & x_{\text{lat4}} & x_{\text{alt4}} & x_{\text{space4}} & x_{\text{corner4}} & x_{\text{snow4}} \\
>  x_{\text{tem5}} & x_{\text{pressure5}} & x_{\text{hum5}} & x_{\text{lat5}} & x_{\text{alt5}} & x_{\text{space5}} & x_{\text{corner5}} & x_{\text{snow5}} \\
>  x_{\text{tem6}} & x_{\text{pressure6}} & x_{\text{hum6}} & x_{\text{lat6}} & x_{\text{alt6}} & x_{\text{space6}} & x_{\text{corner6}} & x_{\text{snow6}} \\
>  x_{\text{tem7}} & x_{\text{pressure7}} & x_{\text{hum7}} & x_{\text{lat7}} & x_{\text{alt7}} & x_{\text{space7}} & x_{\text{corner7}} & x_{\text{snow7}} \\
>  x_{\text{tem8}} & x_{\text{pressure8}} & x_{\text{hum8}} & x_{\text{lat8}} & x_{\text{alt8}} & x_{\text{space8}} & x_{\text{corner8}} & x_{\text{snow8}} \\
> \end{array}$

**EDITED**

If you have a different range for each variable, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
makesubs[var_, range_] := Subscript[x, ToString[var] <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range@range
```

Now set your `names` list like this:

```
names = {{"tem", 3}, {"pressure", 2}, {"hum", 4}, {"lat", 2}, {"alt", 7}, {"space", 2},
 {"corner", 3}, {"snow", 4}};
```

Now use it!

```
makesubs[names[[#, 1]], names[[#, 2]]] & /@ Range@Length@names
```

> $\left\{\left\{x_{\text{tem1}},x_{\text{tem2}},x_{\text{tem3}}\right\},\left\{x_{\text{pressure1}},x_{\text{pressure2}}\right\},\left\{x_{\text{hum1}},x_{\text{hum2}},x_{\text{hum3}},x_{\text{hum4}}\right\},\left\{x_{\text{lat1}},x_{\text{lat2}}\right\},\left\{x_{\text{alt1}},x_{\text{alt2}},x_{\text{alt3}},x_{\text{alt4}},x_{\text{alt5}},x_{\text{alt6}},x_{\text{alt7}}\right\},\left\{x_{\text{space1}},x_{\text{space2}}\right\},\left\{x_{\text{corner1}},x_{\text{corner2}},x_{\text{corner3}}\right\},\left\{x_{\text{snow1}},x_{\text{snow2}},x_{\text{snow3}},x_{\text{snow4}}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: yes!! but what about the rest?

Comment: @Alex You mean all other variables? Like "pressure", "hum", "lat", etc?

Comment: yes you wrote it just for "tem",that is alright.I need it for all for "pressure" etc

Comment: @Alex Please see my edit.

Comment: I need exactly what you got in the Subscripts of "X".like X"temp1",X"temp2",....

Comment: @Alex Please see again... I've just edited the post.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the accept! :-)

Comment: Thanks for you help and skills my friend.

Comment: One more thing what if the number of subscripts going to vary in different variables?Like "tem"= 8 and "lat"=12

Comment: @Alex You could then table the variables individually...

Comment: Could you please write the code?

Comment: @Alex Please see it again...

Comment: How can I up vote it again???You have to be my guest for a drink in Finland then!!

Comment: @Alex LOL! I would love it! Meanwhile I keep drinking some caipirinhas here in Brazil! :-P (P.S. 2 upvotes are not possible, but maybe you could accept [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25775/can-i-use-googlemap-or-other-gps-data-in-creation-of-the-graphs/25780#25780)).

Comment: Rod your answer is great and you can see everybody liked that but you know this is still not what I needed.We can discuss about it later if you like.My knowledge in programming is next to zero but I have some knowledge in Graph theory.Can we talk about it in near future?Maybe 2-3 days later?

Comment: @Alex Of course! I thought you had "forgotten" the question, LOL ! Please tell me later what exactly you need! It will be a pleasure to help!

Comment: Rod how long have you been working with MMA and personally what is your opinion about Matlab and MMA?

Comment: @Alex I've written my master thesis in MMA 10 years ago... :-P But I'm still a newbie here... :-(

Comment: sorry Rod but it is much better version of your work.you still have my invitation to a drink "PLus" Mr. Goldberg!!

Comment: Can we write it in the very general term of `Subscript[x, Subscript["a", "i"], Subscript["b", "j"], Subscript["c", "k"], Subscript["d", "f"], Subscript["...", "..."]]`??

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm missing some subtlety of the question but it seems to me that you could merely do:

```
MapIndexed[
 Subscript[x, #, #2[[1]]] &,
 {"tem", "pressure", "hum", "lat", "alt", "space", "corner"}
]
```

> $\left\{x_{\text{tem},1},x_{\text{pressure},2},x_{\text{hum},3},x_{\text{lat},4},x_{\text{alt},5},x_{\text{space},6},x_{\text{corner},7}\right\}$

---

I failed to understand your original quesiton, but looking at the update here is another section of code that produces the same output.  Whether or not it is better I don't know.

```
Outer[
  Subscript[x, ##] & @@ Subscript @@@ Partition[{##}, 2] &,
  {"a", "b"}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {"i", "j"}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {"m", "n"},
   {1, 2}, {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but you know that is not we discussing here if you look carefully.

Comment: @Alex I couldn't figure out what you meant by "to get something like x"tem""1", x"tem""2", and so on?"  Would `MapIndexed[Subscript[x, Row@{#, #2[[1]]}] &, {"tem", "pressure", "hum", "lat", "alt", 
  "space", "corner"}]` serve your purpose?

Comment: I already had two brilliant answers to my question.Please look at the answers,that show what I want.

Comment: Mr. Wizard could you please participate to broaden Mr. Goldberg code to very general form of `Subscript[x, Subscript["a", "i"], Subscript["b", "j"], 
 Subscript["c", "k"], Subscript["d", "f"], Subscript["...", "..."]]`?

Comment: @Alex I editing my answer with a small variation of the code presently in the question.  I don't know if it helps, or if that's the kind of thing you're seeking.

Comment: thanks Mr Wizard.Actually I have got what I wanted originally from two previous answers; but your mentioned point raised my curiosity to broaden what I wanted.I have them already many thanks.