# What should I do if the geographical map provided by Mathematica doesn't show some rivulets?

Tags: image-processing, geography

I have a list of geographical coordinates(maybe the coordinates are not that accurate, but the problem is not that vital):

```
 geodata = {{"30\[Degree]16'38.43''N", 
 "120\[Degree]10'55.54''E"}, {"30\[Degree]16'18.17''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'2.03''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'58.53''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'2.58''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'38.9''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'0.67''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'29.61''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'0.63''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'21.84''N", 
 "120\[Degree]10'59.94''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'10.91''N", 
 "120\[Degree]10'57.55''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'52.85''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'48.06''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'46.65''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'25.2''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'36.61''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'10.54''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'26.53''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'59.61''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'16.68''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'45.45''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'1.32''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'40.07''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'51.96''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'36.82''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'35.73''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'22.55''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'40.19''N", 
 "120\[Degree]13'10.21''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'28.39''N", 
 "120\[Degree]13'0.05''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'9.78''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'43.92''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'58.1''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'33.66''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'38.61''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'16.68''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'33.41''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'12.38''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'21.62''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'1.76''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'51.43''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'7.32''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'59.66''N", 
 "120\[Degree]12'1.47''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'7.55''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'55.81''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'13.21''N", 
 "120\[Degree]11'51.7''E"}} // GeoPosition;
```

And I want to show those points in one picture with the background being the local map.

At first I tried

```
GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[geodata], ImageSize -> 600]
```

as you can see,

[image: here]

there should be a rivulet at every geomarker, just as the one on the left of the picture. But the map *Mathematica* originally provided is not precise enough, the rest rivulets are not shown here(**Those rivulets are very important!**).
Then I used `GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]` and `GeoStyling["ContourMap"]` to specify a small region just to make it present better,

```
<< "ComputationalGeometry`";
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["ContourMap"], Polygon[#]},ImageSize -> 600] &[
Extract[geodata[[1]], List /@ ConvexHull[geodata[[1]]]] // 
GeoPosition]
```

(Here **ComputationalGeometry** package and `ConvexHull` are used to generate a convexhull, they don't matter much) but you will see that the polygon is just a piece of green, the same problem still remains.

So what should I do to make the map more precise that can show the small rivulets? Thanks!

**Edit:** I have thought to use google earth to screenshot the map, but the rivulets are too thin to distinguished from the background, it's hard to use image-processing method.

And, if I use google map, but google map doesn't support multi-geomarkers like 26, I can't show every geomarkers on google map. Or else, I firstly take the screenshot, then add the geomarkers, but I think it's not easy to place the geomarkers at accurate places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What datum was used for your geodata? Google Maps uses WGS84/Pseudo-Mercator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) and it does not seem to align well with your data.

The following was copied from Mark McClure ([How to combine more locations (GPS coordinates inside one city) with Google map?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46573/how-to-combine-more-locations-gps-coordinates-inside-one-city-with-google-map?lq=1))

```
geodata = {
    {"30\[Degree]16'38.43''N", 
     "120\[Degree]10'55.54''E"}, {"30\[Degree]16'18.17''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'2.03''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'58.53''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'2.58''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'38.9''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'0.67''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'29.61''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'0.63''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'21.84''N", 
     "120\[Degree]10'59.94''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'10.91''N", 
     "120\[Degree]10'57.55''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'52.85''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'48.06''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'46.65''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'25.2''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'36.61''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'10.54''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'26.53''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'59.61''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'16.68''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'45.45''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'1.32''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'40.07''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'51.96''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'36.82''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]14'35.73''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'22.55''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'40.19''N", 
     "120\[Degree]13'10.21''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'28.39''N", 
     "120\[Degree]13'0.05''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'9.78''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'43.92''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]14'58.1''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'33.66''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'38.61''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'16.68''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]14'33.41''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'12.38''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'21.62''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'1.76''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'51.43''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'7.32''E"}, {"30\[Degree]14'59.66''N", 
     "120\[Degree]12'1.47''E"},
    {"30\[Degree]15'7.55''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'55.81''E"}, {"30\[Degree]15'13.21''N", 
     "120\[Degree]11'51.7''E"}} //
   GeoPosition;
markerString[{lat_, lng_}] := 
  "&markers=" <> ToString[lat] <> "," <> ToString[lng];
url = StringJoin[Flatten[{
     "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=800x500&\
zoom=14",
     markerString /@ geodata[[1]]}]];
Import[url]
```

[image]